# Should I validate input in API or BL layer?

Tags: node.js, validation, user-input, jsonschema

I have a node.js application with an API, BL and DAL layers and I want to validate user input.

Currently I'm doing the validation at the beginning of BL functions so it doubles as a user input validator and an inner application validators (calls from other classes)

I'm worried it's not good practice as the validation may happen multiple times on a single API call for some functions (e.g a function that accepts userId and then sends the userId to other functions, validating the same value multiple times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should validate data when it comes from request to your routes using middleware:

```
router
  .get('/', validators.users.index, actions.users.index)
```

If you wish I can share the rest of the code of validation with `Joi`.